# units error with siunitx

Tags: errors, siunitx

> ! Undefined control
>   sequence.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\si{300}{\nanogram\per\millilitre}
\end{document}
```

Why?

Comment: While in this case it was easy enough to guess the message you were getting, it is usually best to post the _full_ text of an error message rather than just part of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use `\SI{<number>}{<unit macros>}` if you want to typeset a number with units (instead of the lowercase `\si`, which typesets just units), and unit prefixes like `\milli` and `\nano` have to be separated from the unit macros `\liter` and `\gram`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{300}{\nano\gram\per\milli\litre}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Jake answered the core question: units and prefixes have to be given separately. However, I think I should add a few comments. There are simply too many potential combinations to provide all of them, and so the core of the package only defines separate prefixes and units. You can define additional units using `\DeclareSIUnit`

```
\DeclareSIUnit\nanogram{\nano\gram}
```

There are a large number of abbreviated units, which currently have to be loaded as an option

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\begin{document}
\SI{300}{\ng\per\ml}
\end{document}
```

(I'm planning to revise this so that they are loaded as standard when I do the v2.3 updates: hopefully this will happen some time in June.)

On the `\si` *versus* `\SI` issue, using `\si` as you have will mean that the package treats `300` as a unit, then does a 'free standing unit' approach to the later part. This is not going to give you the correct output.

Comment: Thanks got the abbrev tip - a real time-saver and reduces text clutter. :)

Comment: When I tried use abbreviations inside a key of a glossary entry, I got error, however, the abbreviations are working inside the main documents. What is probably the reason?

Comment: I posted a MWE about this crash [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/389976/2288)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `\SI` instead of `\si`.