# siunitx abbreviations don't work inside glossaries entries

Tags: glossaries, siunitx

Here, `siunitx` abbreviations throw an error if used inside a glossary entry key, however, if the unit is given without abbreviations, no error shows up.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc,siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newlength\glsnamewidth
\newlength\glsunitwidth

\settowidth{\glsnamewidth}{\textbf{sign}}
\settowidth{\glsunitwidth}{\textbf{unit}}

\newglossarystyle{namedescunit}{%
  \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\linewidth-\glsnamewidth-\glsunitwidth-6\tabcolsep}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{supertabular}{p{\glsnamewidth}p{\glsunitwidth}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \raggedright\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & 
    \centering\glossentrysymbol{##1} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\tabularnewline
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{\glossentry{##2}{##3}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}

\setglossarystyle{namedescunit}

%%%%%%%%% this code block causes the crash %%%%%%%%%%%
    \makeatletter
    \appto\@newglossaryentryposthook{%
        \settowidth{\dimen@}{\glsentryname{\@glo@label}}%
        \ifdim\dimen@>\glsnamewidth
        \setlength{\glsnamewidth}{\dimen@}%
        \fi
        \settowidth{\dimen@}{\glsentrysymbol{\@glo@label}}%
        \ifdim\dimen@>\glsunitwidth
        \setlength{\glsunitwidth}{\dimen@}%
        \fi
    }%
    \makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\glssetnoexpandfield{symbol}
\newglossaryentry{L}{name={L},description={Buchstabe},symbol={---}}
\newglossaryentry{P}{name={Cp},description={specific heat},symbol={[\si{\J\per\kg\per\K}]}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Right, that does throw an *Undefined control sequence* on the abbreviated units. (By the way, `\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}` is actually deprecated syntax, the correct in versions 2.3 and above of `siunitx` would be `\sisetup{abbreviations=true}`, which is also the default behaviour. See manual sections 8.3 and 5.11.)

Comment: Maybe add `\glsnoexpandfields` to the preamble, as discussed in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390273/creating-new-command-including-siunitx-error-due-to-spacing

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I already have `\glssetnoexpandfield{symbol}` in the preamble before the new glossary entries.

Comment: Then you can use that answer's secondary method, that of `\protect`ing those units.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I would be grateful if you could show me a complete syntax of the glossary entry to better understand how to do it.

Comment: The problem can be reduced to `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{etoolbox,siunitx} \newcommand{\tmp}{} \appto\tmp{\settowidth{\dimen0}{[\si{\J\per\kg\per\K}]}} \tmp \begin{document} \end{document}`. (This is essentially what the `glossaries` code is trying to do.) If the `\tmp` block  is moved to the document environment the error goes away.

Comment: Nicola's comment seems to be the proper way to proceed.  Perhaps ask her to provide the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that <strike>`\si`</strike> the `\si` abbreviation commands like `\J` (see Ulrike's answer) can't be processed in the preamble. This can be demonstrated with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\settowidth{\dimen0}{[\si{\J\per\kg\per\K}]}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This causes the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \J 
              \per \kg \per \K
```

Moving `\settowidth` to the document environment gets rid of the error.

This means that the unit width can't be calculated in the preamble for your MWE, but `\makenoidxglossaries` won't permit `\newglossaryentry` in the `document` environment (and it's not recommended with `\makeglossaries`). Instead you can make use of the `\glsFindWidestUsedAnyNameSymbol` command provided with `glossaries-extra-stylemods`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc,siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\usepackage[stylemods]{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newlength\glsnamewidth
\newlength\glsunitwidth

\settowidth{\glsnamewidth}{\textbf{sign}}
\settowidth{\glsunitwidth}{\textbf{unit}}

\newglossarystyle{namedescunit}{%
  \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\linewidth-\glsnamewidth-\glsunitwidth-6\tabcolsep}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{supertabular}{p{\glsnamewidth}p{\glsunitwidth}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \raggedright\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & 
    \centering\glossentrysymbol{##1} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\tabularnewline
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{\glossentry{##2}{##3}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}

\setglossarystyle{namedescunit}

\newglossaryentry{L}{name={L},description={Buchstabe},symbol={---}}
\newglossaryentry{P}{name={Cp},description={specific heat},symbol={[\si{\J\per\kg\per\K}]}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\gls{L}, \gls{P}.


\glsFindWidestUsedAnyNameSymbol{\glsunitwidth}
\settowidth{\dimen0}{\glsgetwidestname}
\ifdim\dimen0>\glsnamewidth
 \glsnamewidth=\dimen0
\fi

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

`\glsFindWidestUsedAnyNameSymbol` only checks entries that have been marked as used (through commands like `\gls`) so needs to be used just before the glossary (provided it's at the end of the document). If you use `\glsaddall` instead, use `\glsFindWidestAnyNameSymbol` which can be placed at the start of the document:

```
\begin{document}
\glsFindWidestAnyNameSymbol{\glsunitwidth}
\settowidth{\dimen0}{\glsgetwidestname}
\ifdim\dimen0>\glsnamewidth
 \glsnamewidth=\dimen0
\fi

\lipsum[1]
\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The definitions for the abbreviations are loaded only at begin document. So you should either move your glossary definition behind `\begin{document}`, not use abbreviations in the glossary definitions or load the abbreviations earlier:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc,siunitx}

%load abbreviations:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\__siunitx_load_abbreviations:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newlength\glsnamewidth
\newlength\glsunitwidth

\settowidth{\glsnamewidth}{\textbf{sign}}
\settowidth{\glsunitwidth}{\textbf{unit}}

\newglossarystyle{namedescunit}{%
  \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\linewidth-\glsnamewidth-\glsunitwidth-6\tabcolsep}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{supertabular}{p{\glsnamewidth}p{\glsunitwidth}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
    {\end{supertabular}}%
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \raggedright\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \centering\glossentrysymbol{##1} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\tabularnewline
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{\glossentry{##2}{##3}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}

\setglossarystyle{namedescunit}

%%%%%%%%% this code block causes the crash %%%%%%%%%%%
    \makeatletter
    \appto\@newglossaryentryposthook{%
        \settowidth{\dimen@}{\glsentryname{\@glo@label}}%
        \ifdim\dimen@>\glsnamewidth
        \setlength{\glsnamewidth}{\dimen@}%
        \fi
        \settowidth{\dimen@}{\glsentrysymbol{\@glo@label}}%
        \ifdim\dimen@>\glsunitwidth
        \setlength{\glsunitwidth}{\dimen@}%
        \fi
    }%
    \makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\glssetnoexpandfield{symbol}
\newglossaryentry{L}{name={L},description={Buchstabe},symbol={---}}
\newglossaryentry{P}{name={Cp},description={specific heat},symbol={[\si{\J\per\kg\per\K}]}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

You could make a feature request for siunitx that it adds a option to load them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similiar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255338/si-unit-in-acronym-glossary). @tomriddle suggested a quite simple solution in comparison to the already provided answers by using `\unexpanded{}` in the entry. I am
no expert if this can cause some problems down the line but the solution worked well in
my document.

Here is an example:

```
\newacronym{MC}{\unexpanded{\si{\micro}C}}{Mikrocontroller}
```