# creating new command including siunitx - error due to spacing (?)

Tags: spacing, macros, siunitx

I have created a new command for the glossarie-package. Especcially for symbols...

```
\newcommand*{\nsymbol}[4]{\newglossaryentry{#1}{
            type=symbols,
            name={#2},
            description={\nopostdesc},
            symbol={{#3}}, 
            user1={#4}, 
            sort={#1}}}
```

The main issue here (i guess) the following line works fine, but the second one gives me an 'Undefiened Control Sequence' and I can't determine whats the problem.

```
\nsymbol{abc}{alphabet}{$A_.{bc}$}{$\si{cm}$}
\nsymbol{abc}{alphabet}{$A_.{bc}$}{$\si{\metre}$}
```

I can only guess, but it seems the newcommand doesnt work quite well with siunitx, since the error says something like:

> ! Undefined control sequence.  \@glo@useri ->$\si {\metre 
>                            }$ l.38 ...alphabet}{$A_.{bc}$}{$\si{\metre}$}

Where there is a space between '\si'  and '{\metre}', maybe this is the problem...
It doesn't make any difference in, whether its mathmode or not.
Thanks in advance, its probably stupid, but I would appreciate any helpful answer.

EDIT:that's kind of a minimal example, not quite sure, what's the problem here, so I copied a lot.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
    \sisetup{detect-mode = false,
    detect-family=true,
    mode=math,
    %               output-decimal-marker={,},
    binary-units=true,
    group-separator={\,},group-minimum-digits=3%
}

        % upright indices-shortcut
\mathcode`\.="8000
\begingroup\lccode`~=`.
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1{\mathrm{#1}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym, symbols, nomain, toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}

%%% new glossary styl
\newglossarystyle{symblongtabu}{
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{
        \begin{longtabu}spread 0pt[l]{ccc<{\strut}l}
        }{
    \end{longtabu}}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{
        \toprule
        \bfseries Formelzeichen & \bfseries Bezeichnung &
        \bfseries Einheit & \bfseries Seite(n)
        \tabularnewline\midrule\endhead
        \bottomrule\endfoot}
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
        \glsentryitem{##1}
        % Entry number if required
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}} &
        \glossentryname{##1} &
        \glsentryuseri{##1} &
        ##2\tabularnewline}}

\makenoidxglossaries

%%% newsymb macro
\newcommand*{\nsymbol}[4]{\newglossaryentry{#1}{
        type=symbols,
        name={#2},
        description={\nopostdesc},
        symbol={{#3}}, 
        user1={#4}, 
        sort={#1}}}
\defglsentryfmt[symbols]{\ifmmode
    \glssymbol{\glslabel}
    \else
    \glsgenentryfmt~\glsentrysymbol{\glslabel}
    \fi}
%%% entries
\nsymbol{abc}{alphabet}{$A_.{bc}$}{$\si{cm}$}
\nsymbol{abc1}{alphabet1}{$A_.{bc1}$}{$\si{\metre}$}

\begin{document}

    \printnoidxglossary[type = symbols, style = symblongtabu]

    \gls{abc} \\
    \gls{abc1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Try `\SI{}{\metre}`

Comment: Done, hope it is good enough. To make it work zou need to comment both second lines...

Comment: Nearly missed your other advice...\SI{}{} doesnt make any difference...white space again before the curly bracket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `\protect` it, as in `\nsymbol{abc1}{alphabet1}{$A_.{bc1}$}{$\si{\protect\metre}$}`

UPDATE: Nicola just provided the Rosetta Stone...adding `\glsnoexpandfields` to the preamble alleviates the need to protect the arguments.  It works to "prevent expansion occurring when the entry's internal commands are set."

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
    \sisetup{detect-mode = false,
    detect-family=true,
    mode=math,
    %               output-decimal-marker={,},
    binary-units=true,
    group-separator={\,},group-minimum-digits=3%
}

        % upright indices-shortcut
\mathcode`\.="8000
\begingroup\lccode`~=`.
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1{\mathrm{#1}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym, symbols, nomain, toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}

%%% new glossary styl
\newglossarystyle{symblongtabu}{
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{
        \begin{longtabu}spread 0pt[l]{ccc<{\strut}l}
        }{
    \end{longtabu}}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{
        \toprule
        \bfseries Formelzeichen & \bfseries Bezeichnung &
        \bfseries Einheit & \bfseries Seite(n)
        \tabularnewline\midrule\endhead
        \bottomrule\endfoot}
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
        \glsentryitem{##1}
        % Entry number if required
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}} &
        \glossentryname{##1} &
        \glsentryuseri{##1} &
        ##2\tabularnewline}}

\makenoidxglossaries

%%% newsymb macro
\newcommand*{\nsymbol}[4]{\newglossaryentry{#1}{
        type=symbols,
        name={#2},
        description={\nopostdesc},
        symbol={{#3}}, 
        user1={#4}, 
        sort={#1}}}
\defglsentryfmt[symbols]{\ifmmode
    \glssymbol{\glslabel}
    \else
    \glsgenentryfmt~\glsentrysymbol{\glslabel}
    \fi}
%%% entries
\nsymbol{abc}{alphabet}{$A_.{bc}$}{$\si{cm}$}
\nsymbol{abc1}{alphabet1}{$A_.{bc1}$}{$\si{\protect\metre}$}

\begin{document}

    \printnoidxglossary[type = symbols, style = symblongtabu]

    \gls{abc} \\
    \gls{abc1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well, that did the trick. Thanks a lot.
Any suggestions on how to solve the issue if I define the units in the newcommand with `user1={$\si{#4}$}` and only write `\nsymbol{abc}{alphabet}{$A_.{bc}$}{\metre}` ? Reason here would be the time to add new ones...

Comment: @Djiwahwah I am sorry, but I have no direct workaround for the requirement to `\protect` the argument of `\si`.

Comment: @Djiwahwah While something like `\let\svsi\si
\def\si#1{\svsi{\protect#1}}` *might* get you out of the immediate jam, it would fail if the `\si` argument contained more than one token needing `\protect`ion, such as `\metre\squared`.  So I don't have a general fix.

Comment: alright, but thanks anyway. Its just, sad that I have to protect every token

Comment: @Djiwahwah If I think of a way out, I will post an update.

Comment: `\newcommand{\p1}[1]{\si{\protect\#1}}
\newcommand{\p2}[2]{\si{\protect\#1\protect\#2}}` might work...you can easily extend it and it is not very nice but a way to go...
Thanks for your continued effort

Comment: @Djiwahwah except that neither `\p1`  nor `\p2` are valid macro names since `1` and `2` are not an alphabetic catcode.  I think this might be a case of "the cure is worse than the ailment"

Comment: It's simpler to just add `\glsnoexpandfields` to prevent expansion occurring when the entry's internal commands are set then you don't need `\protect`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thank you.  Do you wish to add an answer, or shall I modify mine to take your advice?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It's alright. You can just modify yours.

Comment: @Djiwahwah See Nicola's comment.  She just solved the riddle for you.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: yeah, the cure I thught of wasnt helpful at all...But thanks a lot to you both!

Comment: One last thing, this solution does make it possible to use only the unit-token within `\nsymb` such as `\ampere` if you set `user1={$\si{#4}$}` -  might be helpful to somebody